# Issues with overflow:hidden in Chrome on a 'retina' display

Tags: css, google-chrome, graphics, retina

I have a CSS problem that only occurs in Google Chrome. Objects set to `overflow: hidden` are being 'clipped' at the edges when within a horizontally centred container, and only at 
odd browser widths, and only on a high-res display.

HTML:

```
<html><body>
  <div id="container">
     <div class="sprite"> </div>
  </div>
</body></html>
```

CSS:

```
#container
{
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px);
}

.sprite
{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.sprite:after
{
  content: ' ';
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("/img/sprite@2x.png");
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  -webkit-background-size: 30px 30px;
  -moz-background-size: 30px 30px;
  -o-background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-size: 30px 30px;
}
```

Now, as I resize the width of the window, at odd window widths the sprite gets clipped either side on my retina display. It does not occur on a standard (1 css pixel to 1 display pixel) display.

[image]

This apparent rendering bug does not occur in Safari or Firefox. This is on OS X 10.9.3 running Chrome 35.

Edit: It also happens with a pure CSS circle shape, so doesn't seem related to the use of a background image.

Comment: try setting a width and height on the :after too

Comment: @Pete forgot to put that in my simplified example. That was already set (image would have been largely invisible without it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My example was too over-simplified so the problem didn't occur standalone.

It turns out that, via a SASS mixin in my full application, I had the following applied to the panel containing the sprite (edit question to include it)

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px);
```

This was there to improve CSS performance with hardware acceleration where available (mainly iOS).

Removing this improves the situation slightly, so it seems less likely to 'clip' the shape when resizing the window.

However removing `overflow: hidden` from the `:after` element seems to have solved it entirely.

It is worth noting that this 'clipping' side-effect occurs even with a pure CSS circle, it's not related to background-images (thanks @Rohit).

This seems to be a rendering bug rather than something I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**Hey now you can try this with out image**

**Css**

```
#container
{
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.sprite
{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:30px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.sprite:after
{
  content: ' ';
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
  background:#eecc00;
    border-radius:50%;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
     <div class="sprite">! </div>
  </div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/96wfP/1/)**

Comment: It does the same thing with a pure CSS circle (no image)